# Return files only by strict path

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a strange behavior of apache. I have file test.php in virtual server root and it's opens by url: `example.com/test.php`, but if I try to open this url `example.com/test.php/noexists.php` I also see content of `example.com/test.php` file.
File `noexists.php` dosen't exists on server, but server doesn't return 404 error. How to get 404 error for non existing files?

Apache 2.2, virtual server config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: do you have any `.htaccess` file in this DocumentRoot?

Comment: @regilero, no, there is only one file test.php in DocumentRoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> " assume the location `/test/` points to a directory that contains only
>   the single file `here.html`. Then requests for `/test/here.html/more`
>   and `/test/nothere.html/more` both collect `/more` as PATH_INFO "
>    [[source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)]

That is the default behaviour. However you can change it by using this in your apache config files.

```
AcceptPathInfo Off
```